# Update SharePoint list entry using ListData.svc and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, odata, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to update a SharePoint 2010 list entry using PowerShell ***without*** using the SharePoint client?  If so, how?

To get the desired fields, I would:

```
$url = 'http://myserver/resource/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/TheList(1234)?$select=Id,Title,StartingDate,Hours'

$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials
[xml]$xml = $webRequest.Content

$properties = $xml.feed.entry.content.properties
$properties | Format-Table -Property Id,Title,StartingDate,EndingDate,Hours
```

I would like to modify the `EndingDate` and `Hours` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to update List Item using [SharePoint REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Update Lst Item
.DESCRIPTION
    Updates List Item operation using SharePoint 2010 REST Interface.
    To  update an existing entity, you must perform the following actions:
      - Create an HTTP request using the POST verb.
      - Add an X-HTTP-Method header with a value of MERGE.
      - Use the service URL of the list item you want to update as the target for the POST
      - Add an If-Match header with a value of the entity’s original ETag.
    Follow http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/ for a more details
.EXAMPLE
   Update-ListItem -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.com" -ListName "Tasks" -ItemId 1 -Properties $ItemProperties
#>
Function Update-ListItem()
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$WebUrl,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$ListName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [int]$ItemId, 
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [Hashtable]$Properties
)

    #construct endpoint for updaing of List Item   
    $endpointUrl = "$WebUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/$ListName($ItemId)"

    $headers = @{
       "X-HTTP-Method" = "MERGE";
       "If-Match" = "*"
    }

    $ItemPayload = $Properties | ConvertTo-Json

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpointUrl -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $ItemPayload
}
```

**Usage**

```
#Update Task list item
$ItemProperties = @{  
       Title = "Approval Task"; 
       StartDate = "2014-04-24T00:00:00"}
Update-ListItem -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.com" -ListName "Tasks" -ItemId 1 -Properties $ItemProperties
```

---

As an alternative you could also utilize [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) instead of [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx), for example:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $EndpointUrl -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $ItemPayload
```

Comment: Why would I choose Invoke-RestMethod versus Invoke-WebRequest?  Is there a way to increment a field's value by setting a formula in the hash?  Something like `@{Hours = Hours + 0.25}`?

Comment: have you considered packaging this PowerShell function (and the remain CRUD operations) into a single PowerShell module, like what you did with your [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) repo?

Comment: that's a great question :) was thinking about that since [PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) covers only a small subset of API

Comment: I'd contribute to the project.